# Agrupar datos por semana sin repeticiones

Tags: postgresql

Necesito agrupar por fecha a los pacientes que son los `supplementalid` de dos tablas unidas, para mi el código debe estar correcto pero el resultado en lugar de agruparme 2 en la semana 7 y 8 me pone 1 y 1 ):

```sql
select 
  count(dat.supplementalid), 
  extract('week' from dat."VISDAT"::date) as dte

from tv."VSDAT" as dat
  left join tv."IE" as ie
    on dat.supplementalid = ie.supplementalid 
    and dat.studyeventoid = ie.studyeventoid

where ie."IEYN" = 'N' 

group by dte, dat."VISDAT"

order by dat."VISDAT"
```

Resultado:

```
count  |   dte

  1    |    48

  1    |    49

  1    |    52

  1    |     2

  1    |     4

  1    |     7

  1    |     7

  1    |     8

  1    |     8
```

Comment: Suena a que solo necesitas agrupar por `dte`, es decir, `group by dte` y nada mas

Comment: @marcos Si puse al inicio solo **group by**  **dte**  pero al correr me dice que debo agregar también  VISDAT y da ese resultado, no esta agrupando correctamente

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar la estructura de las tablas?

Comment: El problema es que estás ordenando por `dat."VISDAT"` (por eso te dice que `dat."VISDAT"` debería aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY. Deberías ordenar por `dte` y quitar  `dat."VISDAT"` de la cláusula GROUP BY. Al agrupar también por  `dat."VISDAT"` las fechas distintas (pero de la misma semana) las agrupa por separado.